# Deploy istio gateway on a specific kubernetes node

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, istio, servicemesh

In a multi cluster, single mesh with namespace tenancy setup with Istio (purely to have over 5,000 nodes), I would like to create a gateway and assign it to specific nodes, the current docs does not cover this for a gateway [here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/gateway/) however the IstioOperator does [here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/istio.operator.v1alpha1/#KubernetesResourcesSpec) via NodeSelector

How would I go about assigning specific nodes (and where possible specific public IPs for the Istio Gateway)

I have looked into a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67373027/istio-run-ingress-gateway-on-every-node), however I do not see any proper documented approach to this issue.

**EDIT** I would like the Gateway to be the sole ingress for all namespaces on the cluster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Gateway` object is no more than `Envoy` config for `istio-ingressgateway` pod which is an `Envoy` proxy.

So, if you want your gateway to be deployed on a specific node, you should add the `nodeSelector` or `nodeAffinity` to the `Deployment` object of `istio-ingressgateway`.

**EDIT**

Assuming you have `istioctl` downloaded.

```
$ kubectl label no worker-1-v1-21 istio-gatewaynode=valid
$ istioctl manifest generate --set profile=demo > istio.yaml
$ vim istio.yaml
```

Search for the `Deployment` called `istio-ingressgateway`, and add teh following lines to `nodeAffinity` sectio as follows:

```
      ...
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: kubernetes.io/arch
            operator: In
            values:
            - amd64
            - ppc64le
            - s390x
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution: <-
        nodeSelectorTerms:                            <- 
        - matchExpressions:                           <- add
          - key: istio-gatewaynode                    <- these
            operator: In                              <- lines
            values:                                   <-
            - valid                                   <-
  containers:
  - args:
  ...
```

Install istio with the generated yaml:

```
# kubectl create -f istio.yaml
...
# kubectl get po -n istio-system -owide
NAME                                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP               NODE             NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
istio-egressgateway-5547fcc8fc-wntbc    1/1     Running   0          13m   192.168.184.5    worker-2-v1-21   <none>           <none>
istio-ingressgateway-85b7fddd86-mntmz   1/1     Running   0          13m   192.168.166.70   worker-1-v1-21   <none>           <none>
istiod-6659979bdf-vwc4x                 1/1     Running   0          13m   192.168.184.4    worker-2-v1-21   <none>           <none>
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample yaml of such a deployment for reference?

Comment: @EZ-C hard to paste the entire yaml, but I have added some more info on how to do it.